# Is it correct to say "the sixth root of $(-8)^2$ is undefined"?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

a book says the "$6$th root of $(-8)^2$" is undefined "because the sixth root of '$-8$' is undefined"

is this a mistake?

> $\color{#09476C}{\text{STUDY TIP}}$
>   Rational exponents can be tricky, and you must remember that the expression $b^{m/n}$ is not defined unless $\sqrt[n]{b}$ is a real number. This restriction produces some unusual-looking results. For instance, the number $\left(-8\right)^{1/3}$ is defined because $\sqrt[3]{-8}=-2$, but the number $\left(-8\right)^{2/6}$ is undefined because $\sqrt[6]{-8}$ is not a real number.

Comment: Your paraphrase does not agree with the image.

Comment: it's the lower half of the stament.

Comment: No, it isn't, @AlbertoGuerra: what is written in that image you linked is that $\,(-8)^{2/6}\,$ is undefined, and this may dependend on what one means: $\,(-8)^{2/6}=\left((-8)^{1/6}\right)^2\,$ is undefined, yet $\,\left((-8)^{2/6}\right)=\left((-8)^2\right)^{1/6}\,$ is defined...probably they want to stress the importance of *positive* basis to apply exponents rules.

Comment: the book says the whole thing is undefined just because you can write it the way you did applying the root first.

Comment: Exactly, @AlbertoGuerra...and what if you make it the other way around? Well, exponents laws aren't good guys if we don't stick to positive basis!

Comment: so it is their mistake?

Comment: can this be classified as a positive base expressed as the product of two negatives?

Comment: The book is wrong. $(-8)^{2/6}$ is the same as $(-8)^{1/3}$ because $2/6=1/3$. One is just not allowed to rewrite $(-8)^{2/6}$ as $\left((-8)^2\right)^{1/6}$.

Comment: What book is that? Who is the intended audience?

Answer (score 2):

To see whether an operation is defined, one should first examine the definition of the operation. For this question we need first need to see how$$b^{\frac{m}{n}},$$where $m$ and $n$ are nonzero integers, is defined. It may be defined in different ways. However, from the provided context by the OP,

> ... the expression $b^{m/n}$ is not defined unless $\sqrt[n]{b}$ is a real number,

it seems that the author of the text defines it as follows:$$b^{\frac{m}{n}}= \left ( b^{\frac{1}{n}} \right ) ^ m = \left ( \sqrt[n]{b} \right ) ^ m .$$

So, in accordance with this definition, the term$$(-8)^{\frac{2}{6}} = (\sqrt[6]{-8})^2$$is undefined because the $n$-th root, $n$ even, of a real number is not defined in the set of real numbers and so $\sqrt[6]{-8}$ is undefined.

It should be noted that, regarding this definition, for $\frac{m}{n} = \frac{p}{q}$ we do **not** have the identity$$b^{\frac{m}{n}} = b^{\frac{p}{q}}$$as one of the sides may not be defined. So$$(-8)^{\frac{2}{6}} \, \pmb{\neq} \, (-8)^{\frac{1}{3}} = \sqrt[3]{-8}$$because the left hand side is not defined, as explained above, while the right hand side *is* defined and equals $-2$.

Answer (score -1):

if we cancel exponents we get
$$\sqrt[6]{(-8)^2}=\sqrt[3]{(-8)}=-2$$
and 
$$\sqrt[6]{(-8)^2}=\sqrt[6]{64}=2$$
two distinct values so it is not well defined

Comment: but is it undefined as book states?

Comment: The problem isn't that it's undefined but that you're not allowed to rewrite the expression as $\sqrt[6]{(-8)^2}$.